# Как включить отладчик Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Который встроенный "Debug Extension for Yii 2"
Я так понял он включается по ip-адресу, например

```
'modules' => [
    'debug' => [
        'class' => yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1']
    ]
]
```

Ссылка на доки

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-debug-module.html#$allowedIPs-detail

но я только начал Yii2 осваивать, со структурой проекта ещё не разобрался и банально не могу найти где это...

Туда надо включить мой ip или ip сервера на котором хостится проект?

Comment: по идее IP клиента, то есть того ПК, с которого вы заходите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл, в котором подключаются модули в basic шаблоне, находится в
*./config/web.php*

Код, который включает дебаг панель, по флагу `YII_ENV_DEV`:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
}
```

В параметре `allowedIPs` надо указывать IP клиента (текущего компьютера).